# Server logging - Apache HTTP server

Tags: logging

"In addition, **log files may contain information supplied directly by the client, without escaping. Therefore**, it is possible for malicious clients to insert control-characters in the log files, so care must be taken in dealing with raw logs."

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/logs.html

What does it mean when it says "without escaping" ?

Answer (score 0):

Escaping is when you take for example a CRLF (windows style line feed) and turn it to \r\n which are the 2 "escaped" characters you'd need to do it, \t is tab etc. It renders them into a form where they arent "done" but you know thats where they were and can be turned back into their original form

Answer (score 0):

Read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection#Shell_injection

If I was to escape html, `<a>` would be escaped to `&lt;a&gt;`

This way the code wouldn't be rendered and won't execute (and is thus considered safe).

If I was accepting user input, and rendered their input directly back to other users, someone might put malicious code in there. Eg: `http://myunsafesite.com?comment=<script>alert('i steal cookies')</script>`

While the above example doesn't apply to a log file, it is the same principle on the file system. Successful exploits may allow attackers to create new files and execute code on the web server.